# Windows 10 startup broken

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, fonts

Someone installed too many fonts on a Windows 10 computer we use to create print files.
I tried to fix it by starting in safe mode (ticked the safe mode option on msconfig) and removing all the fonts and copying the standard windows fonts back into the folder.
I then restarted, realized I was still in safe mode, - went back into msconfig to untick safe mode. - restarted again.
Now when the computer boots, it gets to a blue screen with a white dots going round and round and a mouse cursor with a blue spinning circle.
The screen flashes on for about 2 seconds and then off for a second - again and again forever.
I can't open task manager or 
I booted from the CD and rean chkdsk (ran fine) and sfc /scannow (went to 100% and then said it was unsuccessful)
I tried to do a reinstall (keeping my fines) but it said the hard drive was locked :(
I can't figure out how to get to Safe mode :(
If I do get to Safe Mode, I am not sure what I should check for?
Prior to me deleting the fonts and copying the default ones back in, it was working 100%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard Drive Locked Fix:

- Place the Windows 10 installation media inside the PC either a USB or a DVD.
- Reboot the Windows 10 device.
- On the startup screen of windows you will be asked to boot from the DVD or USB stick and you should do so.
- You will get to a Windows setup screen and you will need to left click or tap on the “Next” button.
- In the next window you will need to left click or tap on the “Repair your computer” feature.
- Now you should be in the “Advanced startup options” window.
- Left click or tap on the “Advanced boot options” feature.
- Left click or tap on the “Troubleshoot” feature.
- Left click or tap on the “Advanced options” feature.
- Left click or tap on the “Command prompt” option.
- Now after you have the command prompt window in front of the screen you will need to write the following line: “chkdsk /f C:”
  Note: If your Windows 10 device is installed on another partition than “C:” drive please use the corresponding drive letter in the command above.
- Press the “Enter” to start the check.
- After this operations is finished, reboot the  Windows 10 device and check to see if you get the same error message.

That being said, I'd test a manual font replace. Just get all fonts folder from working device, delete current one, copy the new ones and it should get rid of some problems, but that assumes the new bad fonts are not in use (are not set anywhere in the main GUI).

Comment: Thanks.I re-did the chkdsk, but it still won't let me do the reload. And The startup repair still doesn't run successfully :( - Trying to re-copy a fresh set of fonts again now.

Comment: Copying the fonts off a working system worked. There were some other files in there, an ini and an xml. I think they were important, and the first time I only had the actual font files.

Comment: The .ini and .xml may contain metadata about the available fonts. At least one of them should update automatically. Glad it worked.

Comment: It happened again :( I think there might be a corruption on one of the fonts or something, I was only removing and reinstalling one font, and after restarting, I got the flashing blue and black screen again :( - this time, copying them from a working machine didn't work :(

Comment: Too bad the new windows versions don't have a classic interface anymore (the non-themes version). That would of bypasses this with one command.